# Application using NuxtJs and Asp.net Core in conjunction with Asp.net Core SignalR not working after being deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, nuxt.js, asp.net-core-signalr

I am currently working on a project where we are using [Nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/) for the front-end and [asp.net core api](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis) for the back-end.
Recently I tried to put some live notifications to the client app and went using [asp.net SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr). Everything is working as expected in my local environment, but after deploying both app, in different Azure Service App, the application is not working and here is the error I am getting:

[image: SignalR Error in Azure]

Here is my [Nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/) app code:

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
require("dotenv").config();

export default {
  server: {...},
  mode: "spa",
  head: {...},
  loading: { color: "#fff" },
  css: ["@/assets/css/all.sass"],
  plugins: [
    ...
    "~/plugins/signalrHub.js",
  ],
  
  buildModules: [...],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [...],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {},
  router: {...},
  proxy: {
    "/hub": {
      target: process.env.BASE_URL || "https://myurl.azurewebsites.net",
      ws: true,
    }, // signalr endpoint
  },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {...},
};
```

This is the `signalrHub.js` file that is injected as a plugin in the [Nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/) config file

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";

export default ({ app, store }, inject) => {
  const hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("hub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

  inject("hub", hub);

  hub.on("Connected", (message) => {
    console.info("Connected to SignalR Hub.", message);
  });

  hub.on("Disconnected", (message) => {
    console.warn("Disconnected from SignalR Hub.", message);
  });

  hub.on("SendProcessUpdate", (res) => {
    console.log("Received message from signalr", JSON.stringify(res));
    store.commit("liveNotification/add", res);
  });

  hub.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  });

  // with reconnect capability (async/await, not IE11 compatible)
  async function start() {
    try {
      console.log("Attempting reconnect");
      await hub.start();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setTimeout(() => start(), 5000);
    }
  }

  hub.onclose(async () => {
    await start();
  });

};
```

For the API side I have this:

In the `startup.cs`

```cs
 public partial class Startup
    {
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {...}

        ...

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            InitializeContainer(services);

            ...

            services.AddCors(options =>
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder
                                                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                    .AllowAnyMethod()));

            services.AddSignalR(options =>
            {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(x => x
               .AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader());

           ...
           
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<NotifierHub>("/hub");
            });
        }
    }
```

Then I defined the Hubs this way:

```cs
public class NotificationService: INotificationService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<NotifierHub, INotificationClient> _notificationHubContext;

        public NotificationService(IHubContext<NotifierHub, INotificationClient> notificationHubContext)
        {
            _notificationHubContext = notificationHubContext;
        }

        public async Task SendProcessUpdate(ProgressNotificationDto updateMessage)
        {
            await _notificationHubContext.Clients.All.SendProcessUpdate(updateMessage);
        }

        public async Task SendProcessUpdateMessageOnly(string message)
        {
            await _notificationHubContext.Clients.All.SendProcessUpdate(new ProgressNotificationDto{Message = message, Id = Guid.NewGuid()});
        }
    }
```

```cs
public class NotifierHub : Hub<INotificationClient>
    {
    }
```

Then I inject the service where I want to use it:

In my `FileConverter.cs` file

```cs
public static void Configure(INotificationService notificationService)
        {
            _notificationService = notificationService;
        }
...

_notificationService.SendProcessUpdate(new ProgressNotificationDto
                {
                    Message = $"Processing file {100 * count / rows.Count()}%",
                    Id = notificationId,
                    Type = ProgressNotificationType.Progress,
                    StartTime = startTime
                });
```

What I am doing wrong? Why is not working in Azure?

Comment: If this is working on dev and not in production, isn't it just a domain name whitelisting required on Signal?

Comment: @kissu mmmm, dont know what u are referring to, I am a newbie with this matter, about the whitelisting but let me search about it

Comment: Signal cannot be used anywhere on the web, it needs to be explicitly whitelisted to work, as many other services I guess. At least, it's one of the few things that may change when migration from local to a production env.